# RXJS retryWhen operator does not return data in case of error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable object like the following. When I subscribe, it doesn't write anything to the console in case of an error. i know I can print it to the console in a pipe, but I need a lot more than that. When I subscribe, I also want data to be received in case of an error.

```
      const publisher = this.http.post<string>('/monitor-status', { data }).pipe(
                tap(res => {
                    if (res === 'down') {
                        throw res;
                    }
                }),
                retryWhen(err => err.pipe(delay(3000)))
       );

      publisher.subscribe({
                next: data => console.log(data), // not printing
                error: err => console.error(err) // not printing
      })
```

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, it should probably find itself inside a service method. Are you calling this service method anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

`retryWhen` is stopping the error from reaching the subscribe error block, just move the code of error to the `retryWhen` like so.

Also note the code you have written will never end if it continues failing! that is why next and error are never called, try to change your approach so that it fails after 3 retries or something like that!

```
const publisher = this.http.post<string>('/monitor-status', { data }).pipe(
            tap(res => {
                if (res === 'down') {
                    throw res;
                }
            }),
            retryWhen(err => {
                console.error(err);
                return err.pipe(delay(3000))
            })
   );

  publisher.subscribe({
            next: data => console.log(data), // not printing
            error: err => console.error(err) // not printing
  })
```

Comment: @Zelen does this answer fix your issue?